# why vue watch only triggered once?

Tags: vue.js

Why watch only triggered once? As code below, when click 'sync' button, id and text changed at the same time, but only id() watch triggered, need to click 'sync' button again to trigger text() watch, why?

```js
Vue.component('test-bar', {
  props: ['id', 'text'],
  template: `
      <div>
        <div>child: {{id}} {{text}}</div>
        <button @click="on_click">sync</button>
      </div>
      `,
  watch: {
    id() {
      this.$emit('update:id', this.id)
      // this.$emit('update:text', this.text) // !!! notice here. only when i added this line will trigger text() watch
    },
    text() {
      this.$emit('update:text', this.text)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    on_click() {
      this.id = 1
      this.text = 'child text'
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    id: 0,
    text: 'parent text',
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test-bar :id.sync='id' :text.sync='text'></test-bar>
  <div>parent: {{id}} {{text}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not update `props`. When trying to update a prop Vue will throw an error and your flow will break. So after this line `this.id = 1` an exception will be thrown and the next line will not execute. The proper way to do this is to use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) with a getter and a setter.

Something similar to this:

```js
Vue.component('test-bar', {
  props: ['id', 'text'],
  template: `
  <div>
    <div>child: {{childId}} {{childText}}</div>
    <button @click="on_click">sync</button>
  </div>
  `,
  computed: {
    childId: {
      get () {
        return this.id
      },
      set (value) {
        this.$emit('update:id', value)
      }
    },
    childText: {
      get () {
        return this.text
      },
      set (value) {
        this.$emit('update:text', value)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    on_click() {
      this.childId = 1
      this.childText = 'child text'
    }
  }
})
```

Here's a jsfiddle working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/hapd68w7/5/)

A simpler way would be to just emit the event and not watch for the changes

```
on_click() {
  this.$emit('update:id', 1)
  this.$emit('update:text', 'child text')
}
```

JSfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/fhgywbr1/)